# Does the phrasal verb "show X around" need an indirect object?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I am not sure if the phrasal verb "show X around" needs an indirect object, X being a direct object. I am thinking you need to show a person around somewhere, but I am also thinking it might not be necessary given the context might make it clear, but I am not sure if you can just omit it.

Here's an example sentence, so that the question is more easily understood:

> The plant manager showed investors around the plant.

Comment: No: The PP "around the plant" is complement of "showed". It's a complement because it's required for this sense of "showed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say both, and you don't have to be too explicit about the place: it's the place where the people are.

- The plant manager **showed investors around the plant**
- The plant manager welcomed the investors to the plant and **showed them around**
- Welcome.  Let me **show you around.**

Comment: Yes, but the OP's question was about indirect objects. "Around the plant" is not indirect object of "showed", though it is a complement of it.